# Language that W3C XML Recommendation uses to present definitions

Tags: xml, specifications, w3c

I am trying to read W3C recommendation for XML, and I found myself a bit puzzled by the language used to define things, the one that uses `::=` notation.

Most of the time those definitions look like regular expressions:

```
STag       ::=      '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '>'
```

But from time to time I come across strange notation, like the following:

```
Comment    ::=      '<!--' ((Char - '-') | ('-' (Char - '-')))* '-->'
```

What does `Char - '-'` mean? Match anything that `Char` matches excluding `'-'`?

Where can I find formal definition of that language? I tried to search via "::=" but Google just ignores it. The W3C recommendation itself doesn't have any information on the matter.

Comment: It's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form, or one of its derivatives, most likely.

Comment: In fact, following links from there, I get to https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one of very many variants of BNF (Backus Naur Form) - which as you point out has similarities to regular expressions.

The "except" operator ("-") is a little unusual, in my experience. `(Char - '-')` means "Anything that matches Char and does not match '-'" - that is, any character except a hyphen.

The particular flavour of BNF that the XML specification uses is described in section 6 of the spec:

https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-notation

Answer (score 0):

From the [XML recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-notation):

> The formal grammar of XML is given in this specification using a
>   simple Extended Backus-Naur Form (EBNF) notation.

and explains:

> 'string' matches a literal string matching that given inside the
>   single quotes.